# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable being thrown after a for-loop that is iterating over a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, typeerror

I have a DataFrame called `data` and when printed it looks like this:

```
          open      high       low     close     volume                 date
0     128.5900  129.0000  128.5500  128.8400  1607676.0  2021-01-20 06:30:00
1     128.8300  129.3400  128.7600  129.2219   666924.0  2021-01-20 06:31:00
2     129.2400  129.3000  129.0200  129.0400   518878.0  2021-01-20 06:32:00
3     129.0399  129.1700  128.9300  129.0400   386088.0  2021-01-20 06:33:00
4     129.0300  129.3600  129.0033  129.3400   438125.0  2021-01-20 06:34:00
...        ...       ...       ...       ...        ...                  ...
3895  135.2400  135.2711  134.9800  135.0079   306330.0  2021-02-02 12:55:00
3896  135.0050  135.1500  134.9900  135.1300   248848.0  2021-02-02 12:56:00
3897  135.1300  135.1900  135.0600  135.0800   238290.0  2021-02-02 12:57:00
3898  135.0850  135.0900  134.9200  134.9450   504350.0  2021-02-02 12:58:00
3899  134.9500  135.1900  134.8500  134.9800  1586924.0  2021-02-02 12:59:00
```

Then I have this loop that just iterates through the columns I want, to find the average of.

```
bar_range_list = []
for num in range(len(data)):
    top = data.loc[num]['high']
    bottom = data.loc[num]['low']
    range = top - bottom
    bar_range_list.append(range)

average_bar = sum(bar_range_list)/ len(bar_range_list)
print(average_bar)
```

This prints:

```
0.19887697435897464
```

Then I have another loop:

```
volume_list = []
for nums in range(len(data)):
    volume = data.loc[nums]['volume']
    volume_list.append(volume)

average_volume = sum(volume_list) / len(volume_list)
print(average_volume)
```

I want it to just print the average volume throughout the DataFrame, however instead it prints this:

```
for nums in range(len(data)):
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why this error is being thrown when the loop is working identically to the one above and no error is being thrown. I tried changing the nums variable however nothing changed. Why is this happening?

Comment: `range` is a built in function in python. In your first loop look you assign `range=top-bottom` then you try using `for nums in range(len(data)):`. In the first loop change `range=top-bottom` to `RANGE=top-bottom`.

Comment: Thank you so much!